# If custom image header does not exist display text header

Tags: customization, images, headers, text

I've added a theme options page to my site (in my functions.php file):

```
add_custom_image_header('', 'admin_header_style');
```

My header.php contains this code, which displays the Featured Image as the banner. If a Featured Image isn't provided it uses the uploaded image banner from the custom image header.

```
<?php //Custom header
// Check if this is a post or page, if it has a thumbnail, and if it's a big one
if ( is_singular() &&
has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) &&
( /* $src, $width, $height */ $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'post-thumbnail' )) &&
$image[1] >= HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH ) :
// We have a new header image!
echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'post-thumbnail', array('usemap' => '#Map') );
else : ?>
<img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" usemap="#Map" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

My question is, how can I modify this code to output an h1 text header (i.e. `bloginfo('name');`) if no banner image has been uploaded (to the site or post)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php //Custom header
// Check if this is a post or page, if it has a thumbnail, and if it's a big one
if ( is_singular() &&
has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) &&
( /* $src, $width, $height */ $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'post-thumbnail' )) &&
$image[1] >= HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH ) :
// We have a new header image!
echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'post-thumbnail', array('usemap' => '#Map') );
elseif ( $img_src = get_header_image () ) : ?>
<img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" usemap="#Map" />
<?php else: ?>
<h1><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></h1>
<?php endif; ?>
```